# How to write Unit test for DAL which call stored procedure and direct SQL commands

Tags: c#, ado.net, xunit

I am writing unit test cases for DAL methods (which are calling stored procedures and some direct SQL commands and not returning methods). How can I mock the results coming from db in unit tests?

Please let me know sample references or suggestions. Please find the below sample code

```
public class Notification : Base, INotificationBal
{
    public void InsertNotification(NotificationType notif)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnction())
        {
            using (var command = CreatSqlCommand(con, "sp_InsertNotifDetails"))
            {
                // notif.NotificationType=1, notif.NotificationName="Mobile"
                command.SetParamsValues(
                        ("@NotificationType", notif.NotificationType),
                        ("@NotificationName", notif.NotificationName)
                        ));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Sam

I am not aware of this.

Comment: It depends on what your code looks like and how its architected. Are you using interfaces, or Dependency Injection? Can you give us an example of a method that needs to be unit tested?

Comment: Used Interface here. I updated the post with sample code

Comment: Side note: if you're using SQL Server, you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!